# Trigger that will control the entry of the discount amount

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

> Create a trigger that will allow you to control the entry of the discount amount so that it does not exceed 20% of the Sale Price.

```
Сreate trigger [dbo].[Control]
on [dbo].[Ordered Goods]
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
AS
BEGIN 
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  IF EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM Inserted I
    WHERE I.Discount > (0.20*I.Priceproduct)
    ) BEGIN
    -- Should be using throw
    RAISERROR(N'Error',16,1);
  END;
END;
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/voXFO.png)

Comment: it would be nice if you translate the column names, table names trigger name

Comment: And please don't use images for table structure, provide the create table statement as formatted (code) text.

Comment: okay man, pls help me my problem.

Comment: Please keep your language gender neutral unless you know someone prefers to be called "man"

Comment: Okay Excuse please

Comment: What help do you need? It looks like it will prevent a discount of >20% from being added?

Comment: Yes, So that it compares with the sale price

Comment: I don't understand, change you query to use sale price? I can't see you table definition to know which column it is anyway. Table definition + Sample Data + Desired results would make this question a whole lot clearer.

Comment: Example: There is, for example, an order 1 warehouse 1 quantity 10 sale price 200 discount should be no more than 20% of the sale price, i.e. if we have 200 sale prices, then we cannot write 100 because it is more than 20% discount

Comment: [edit] any clarifications into your question. Nowhere in your question do you show us where sale price is... so how do we know where to find it?

Comment: She column table Ordered Goods in photo

Comment: As already requested, please don't use images to show table definitions, and there is no column called ordered goods.

Comment: Ordered goods is a table, and they asked me where the sale price is, and I wrote that the column of the table Ordered goods